# Run cron job in TypeScript NodeJS app whenever deployment to ELB takes place

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a app to my ELB server, and trigger a cron job whenever this happens.

Unsure how to make it work? Here is my setup below. Can anybody help?

**container.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_cron_jobs:
    command: "rm /etc/cron.d/cron_job || exit 0"
  02_start_cron_jobs:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/batch_job.txt > /etc/cron.d/cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron_job"
    leader_only: true
```

**batch_job.txt**

```
# The newline at the end of this file is extremely important.  Cron won't run without it.
* * * * * root npm run batch > /dev/null
```

*package.json*

```
"name": "investor-api",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon ./src/server.ts",
  "batch": "nodemon ./src/batch/index.ts"
}
```

**./src/batch/index.ts**

```
import cron from 'node-cron';
import {
  fetchHolders,
  fetchTransactions,
  updateHistory,
} from './schedule.batch';
import { logger } from '../services/winston';

(() => {
  cron.schedule('1 * * * *', function () {
    logger.debug('Start fetching holders');
    fetchHolders().then();
  });

  cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', function () {
    logger.debug('Start fetching transactions');
    fetchTransactions().then();
  });

  cron.schedule('10 * * * *', function () {
    logger.debug('Start updating history');
    updateHistory().then();
  });
})();
```